# What is meaning of "vaarchnam" in siddha kunjika stotram?

Tags: stotra

In the Shri Siddha Kunjika stotram, there is a following verse:

> na sūktaṃ nāpi vā dhyānaṃ na nyāso na vārcanaṃ |2|

[image: Image for reference:(devanagari)]

Comment: Kunjika strotam has different mantra in other sources available on internet! From where you get this book from which you put photo to ask question? Will you please share Photo of the pages further?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the image you have attached:

> Na kavacham na argala stotram kilakam na rahasyakam |
>  Na suktam na api va
>   dhyanam na nyaso **na va archanam** ||

I have broken up few words here (वार्चनम् = वा + अर्चनम्) so that we can understand the meaning better.

Here Lord Shiva is saying that by reciting only this Stotra one gets the fruits of reciting Sri Chandi (Devi Mahatyam).

> Kunjika patha matrena durga patha phalam labhet ||

Now, for reciting Sri Chandi there are certain rules. For example, first one should recite Argala Stotra, Kilaka Stotra, Devi Kavacha etc. One also has to do Nyasa, recite Rigvedokta Devi Sukta, Dhyana sloka and also has to do a archana (worship) before starting the actual recital.

But, in the case of reciting this Siddha Kunjika Stotra none of the above requirements are to be fulfilled.

Na kavacham na argala stotram kilakam na rahasyakam   -- That means Argala/Kilaka and other Kavacha Stotras are not required to be recited here.

Na suktam na api va dhyanam na nyaso na va archanam  --- That means reciting Devi Sukta, reciting Dhyanam or doing Nyasa are not required. Doing worship is also not required.

**Navarchnam -- worship is neither (not even) required.** This is the meaning you are looking for.

Comment: Beautiful answer sir. Na+VA+archnam. Sir, I need a little knowledge more Na=  no, archnam= Worship but what is the meaning of Va? Is it mean "going to" as it sound in napi VA dhaynam?

Comment: @Rajansharma Thanks .. Va means Or .. so Na+Va= Nor .. **nor is worship [required]** - The whole thing means this

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind reply and helping me to understand the above phrases. Your given lesson is an asset for me.

Comment: Pls don't call me sir .. I may be much younger than u in age.. I am very glad that I was being able to help u :) @Rajansharma Pls continue on the site if u wish and post more good questions and answers.