How to do the Chandi path?
How to do the Durga sap Tasha ti or the Chandi path daily as a householder . What are the rules and regulations for the householders and how can a householder do the parayana to get proper blessing of the Devi ? Also are there any negative consequences if the regulations are not followed during Chandi path? Thank you.

Seems like Durga Saptasloki, or Amba Sruti, i.e. 7 slokas for ma Chandi paath can be done by anyone. https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/durga7.html

See this answer -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/30092/4732
